# Onmouseover - incorrect layout?

Tags: php, html

I have the following code in my php file:

```
print "<a onmouseover=document.getElementById('merchantlogo').src='/store/logos/".$infobrand['merchant']."' href='/merchant/".$infobrand['merchant']."'>".$infobrand['merchant']." (".$infobrand['Total'].")</a>"
```

What I'm trying to do is have image box "merchantlogo" change to $infobrand['merchant'] on hover.

The problem is that the names of the merchants have spaced in their names, that I can't easily change.

It appears that these spaces are causing problems and are been treated separately.

Here's how it appears on page source:

```
<a onmouseover=document.getElementById('merchantlogo').src='/store/logos/Next Day DIY' href='/merchant/Next Day DIY'>Next Day DIY (667)</a>
```

I think there needs to be quote marks after the onmouseover? I'm new to PHP and am unsure how to add these in?

Any info would be really helpful!

Cheers
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Change this
print "<a onmouseover=document.getElementById('merchantlogo').src='/store/logos/".$infobrand['merchant']."' href='/merchant/".$infobrand['merchant']."'>".$infobrand['merchant']." (".$infobrand['Total'].")</a>"

to
print "<a onmouseover=\"document.getElementById('merchantlogo').src='/store/logos/".$infobrand['merchant']."'\" href='/merchant/".$infobrand['merchant']."'>".$infobrand['merchant']." (".$infobrand['Total'].")</a>"
```